# Find all $ x \in [0^{\circ},360^{\circ}] $ for which $ |2 \sin(x) − 5| < 4 $.

Tags: trigonometry

I have no idea how to solve this:

> Find all $ 0 \leq x \leq 360^{\circ} $ satisfying $ |2 \sin(x) − 5| < 4 $.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

At first you have to rephrase the inequality, in a more easy way. It is equvivalent to 
$$\sin(x) > \frac{1}{2}$$
If you need another Hint tell it.

Answer (score 1):

$$|2\sin x-5|<4\Longleftrightarrow -4<2\sin x-5<4\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{2}<\sin x<\frac{9}{2}$$

As you can see, the right - rightmost inequality is pretty boring, so you only have to deal with the left - rigthmost one...:)

Comment: As mathjax isn't working right now i am seeing you use `\Longleftrightarrow` instead of `\iff` . Please use the `iff` as the spacing there is a double spacing which respects the importance of the iff

Comment: Thanks for the advice as it saves typing time.

Comment: BTW, lately (1-2 days) the site is misworking badly...

Comment: Yeah i alwas have to relaod the page, will ask it in meta